# Why does .style.display="block" change the length of my table?

Tags: javascript, css

I have two tables that both have the same class and structure. I style the class with CSS and they look just like I want.

The problem is that if one of those tables starts off hidden and is later displayed using JavaScript the outline ive given it shrinks to wherever the text is that it surrounds.

this is the code used to display the table:

```
function setTable(){    
   if(document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display=="none"){
      document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display="block";
   }
   else if(document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display=="block"){
      document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display="none";
   }
}
```

This demo can probly explain it better than I can:

http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedD0D/6Ajyn/1/

1. Why does this happen?
2. What can I do to stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try setting display to table instead of block!

Comment: Man, your a lifesaver! thats been buggin the heck out me all night. Thank you! (Will accept your answer in 8 mins when it lets me)

Comment: IE7 doesn't support `display:table` property.

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Just empty the css display property instead of setting it as `block` or `table`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14995686/1516616)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display="table";
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display="block";
```

JS Fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/6Ajyn/3/

Comment: IE7 doesn't support `display:table` property

Answer (score 2):

if you set display to none, width:100% doesnt noe how to measure the width.

try this:

```
if(document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display=="none"){
document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.width="100%";
}
else if(document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display=="block"){
document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display="none";
}
}
```

Comment: IE7 doesn't support `display:table` property.

Comment: sorry... i was just testing it out. you can use block instead of table and it will work just the same.. will make an edit

Answer (score 1):

Just empty the css `display` property instead of setting it as `block` or `table` like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display=="none"){
    document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display="";
}

else if(document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display==""){
    document.getElementById("forfeitTable2").style.display="none";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ajyn/8/)

Answer (score 1):

To see a full list of possible values for the `display` property see
[style display property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)

When you hide a table to show it again use

```
document.getElementById("tableId").style.display="table";
```

when you hide table row to show it again use

```
document.getElementById("rowId").style.display="table-row";
```