# Why does the position of the element change when I use .style.display = "block"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I am testing my code on Firefox Ver 47 on W7

I have a two inputs for **Hours** and **Minutes, side by side**. As below,

> [Click to view image showing inputs side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwCiM.jpg)

The inputs and buttons are defined as follows

```
<input style="color: green; width: 50px; height: 17px; background-color: lightgrey; " type='number' id="hour1" value="22" min="0" max="23"> 
<input style="color: green; width: 50px; height: 17px; background-color: lightgrey; " type='number' id="min1" value="40" min="0" max="59"> <br>
<input type='button' value="Show custom time" onclick="show()">  
<input type='button' value="Hide Custom time" onclick="hide()">
```

Now, when I click on **'Show custom time'** button, both of the elements get aligned to the left one below the other (I do not want this to happen).

> [Click here to view image showing inputs position shifted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HIMP.jpg)

The **show()** and **hide()** functions execute as below when triggered.

```
function show()
    {
    document.getElementById('hour1').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('min1').style.display = "block";
    }
    function hide()
    {
    document.getElementById('hour1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('min1').style.display = "none";
    }
```

I have partly fixed this by introducing **CSS**

```
#hour1 {position:fixed; top:5px; left:5px;}
#min1 {position:fixed; top:5px; left:70px;}
```

However `position:fixed` gives an undesired floating effect.

Question is **why is the position changing when I am only modifying the display property** and **how to workaround/fix this or am I doing something wrong?**

> If it helps, tried searching online and came across a [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995541/why-does-style-display-block-change-the-length-of-my-table) where `style.display = "block";` changes the sizing of the table. This was overcome by using `style.display = "table";` .

Comment: set `inline-block` instead of `block`

Comment: That did the trick!! This is better than the CSS option in that I can even input text between the two fields like colon `:` Thanks @toby @jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
function show()
    {
    document.getElementById('hour1').style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById('min1').style.display = "inline-block";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`. This should allow the elements to flow as if they were text, but retain their block-like properties.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: I tried 
`#hour1 {display: inline-block; top:5px; left:5px;}
#min1 {display: inline-block; top:5px; left:70px;}` but for this to work i have to use `document.getElementById('hour1').style.display = "";
 document.getElementById('min1').style.display = "";`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which method would be better/ problem free in the long run ? and why?